# Android - Led stops blinking unexpectedly

Tags: android

I have Notification with LED blinking but I encounter strange LED behaviour.

My app is a video recorder. I have an Activity (UI), and a service which records video. When I press Start button the service is started, recording is started and a notification is shown.

The strange thing is that when the activity is in foreground, the LED stops blinking after one second if I press power key and turn the screen off. When the screen is off because of inactivity time, the LED stops blinking after 5 seconds.
I noticed that the LED behaves correctly only when I send the activity to the background by pressing the Home key.

Anyone knows what the problem might be? I have Xperia P with JB 4.1.
I have LightManager app which works correctly even when its activity is in foreground. Of course I performed tests when LightManager was off.